# Retrieving All table column values using loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, vb.net

I have few tables on the page and I need to run a loop to get all column values and save them in a comma separated string (I will pass these strings to hidden fields of ASP.NET page). How can I write a loop so that it can read column values from let's say "Route1" table. Unfortunately I cannot rely on #ID for TR and TD just because users can shuffle them from one table to anothor using (jQuery).

To put it simple, how I can I write a loop to read through column values of the following table

```html
<table ID = "Route1">
    <tr>
        <td>row 1 col1</td> <td> row1 col2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>row 1 col1</td> <td> row1 col2 </td>
   </tr>
</table>


<table ID = "Route2">
    <tr>
        <td>row 1 col1</td> <td> row1 col2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1 col1</td> <td> row1 col2 </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is a JQUERY related question. I am looking for a loop in JQUERY

Comment: What should your comma separated string look like?

Comment: Right now I am doing this. But I need to perform the same action in a loop  
route1stop1col1 = $('#Route1 tr').find("td").eq(0).html();
route1stop1col2 = $('#Route1 tr').find("td").eq(1).html();
route1stop1col3 = $('#Route1 tr').find("td").eq(2).html();

route1stop1 = route1stop1col1 + "," + route1stop1col2 + "," + route1stop1col3

Comment: I suggest you spend a few minutes reading through the [summary list of jQuery methods and selectors](http://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```javascript
var values = [];

$('#Route1 td').each(function () {
    values.push( $(this).text() );
});

var myString = values.join(',');
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/2xpFZ/

Comment: How about if I want to do it Row by Row. Like having a string per row (actually this was my objective which I should have explained)

Comment: Not using the last line (the `.join()`) if you want a string per row. Each element in `values` (the array) is a string that corresponds to a row.

Comment: I took out the last line. But then what should I load in myString variable. Loading "values" directly into mystring is giving me all tds

Comment: This is how I altered the code to achieve required results 

var values = [];

  $('#Route1 td').each(function () {
            values.push($(this).text());
                });

            //    var myString = values.join(',');

                route1stop1 = values[0] + "," + values[1] + "," + values[2]
                alert(route1stop1);

                route1stop2 = values[4] + "," + values[5] + "," + values[6]

                alert(route1stop2);
            });

Comment: You also could do `$('#Route1 td').each( ... )` and `$('#Route2 td').each( ... )` to build your strings route1stop1 and route1stop2 (if I understood, not sure). `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var str = $("table:first").find("td").map(function(){
               return $(this).text()
          }).get().join(',')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/feDgu/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Route1 td').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get().join(',')
```

However a plain JavaScript loop will be much more performant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it in plain javascript:

```
function getTableCells(id) {
    var data = [];
    var cells = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
    }
    return(data.join(","));
}

var str = getTableCells("Route1");
```